# How to split a numbered column into 7 equal parts vertically and sort by date in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, transpose, textjoin

I have asked a very similar question before, but have been unable to reverse engineer a solution for my current problem [1](http://Link%20to%20previous%20problem%20and%20solution).

I have a column of values stacked in the order I would like, but I am trying to get them to be divided by 7 and have each value take up 7 cells. I created the first few lines of a desired output column that shows what the goal is[2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_x_k1K1u1e_Q3xK9I_WgqPQ_JQ8DRfvmXOMqxfThS44/edit#gid=0).

I also tried to have a sort function in there to only show values <= today(), but was unable to make it work.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Sheet1!B2:L/7, Sheet1!A2:A<>"", Sheet1!A2:A<=TODAY())))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(TEXT(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(
 FILTER(Sheet1!B2:L/7, Sheet1!A2:A<>"", Sheet1!A2:A<=TODAY()))), 
 {"@", "@", "@", "@", "@", "@", "@"})))
```

Comment: Hi player0, I am trying to have each cell in the original array create 7 cells out of it. So for B2 there would be 7 cells of B2/7 in the column and so on